# IE 8 and 7 bug when dynamically adding a stylesheet

Tags: internet-explorer, coding-style

I have the following code

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
if (style.textContent) { // FF, Safari
    style.textContent = this.arg.css;
} else {
    style.innerHTML = this.arg.css;// FF, IE
}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

This works fine in all browsers (also IE 9) but for IE7 and IE8, I get the following error

> SCRIPT600: Unknown runtime error

The error points to the line

```
    style.innerHTML = this.arg.css;// FF, IE
```

What's wrong?

Comment: what are the contents of this.arg.css ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try this way

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
var text = this.arg.css;
style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
if (style.styleSheet) {   // for IE
    style.styleSheet.cssText = text;
} else {                // others
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
    style.appendChild(textnode);
}
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
h.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just curious to know how "var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);" is useful?

Comment: that is just a DOM way, it uses appendChild for any new elements (even text)

Comment: I'm seeing some cases in IE8 where style.styleSheet is null, so the if fails and it falls through to the else, which then throws the Unknown Runtime Error.  Any ideas why styleSheet would be null?

Comment: @Herms, if you see some cases for it - then you can maybe track and post the error when it happens? i haven't seen it

Comment: Apparently IE has a limit on the number of stylesheets it allows, and if you've hit that limit this behavior will trigger.  I'm fairly certain that's what I was running into.

Comment: @Herms, as a workaround in this case i may suggest to try using 1 stylesheet, and editing it (changing its `cssText`) each time you make changes

Comment: @Herms, no I bet you're leaving out the line: style.setAttribute("type", "text/css"); which is required for IE8