# how to add css in css file dynmically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have written a js for grid. gird have a feature where i am taking each column width in input like this.

```
mygrid._struct = [{ fieldType : "deltaHedgeType", defaultWidth : 80},
           { fieldType : "quoteccy", defaultWidth : 40 }]
```

So the grid html generate like this

```
<table id="mygrid">
  <tr>
    <td class="deltaHedgeType"></td>
    <td class="quoteccy"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="deltaHedgeType"></td>
    <td class="quoteccy"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i want this css to append in  style.css

```
#mygrid .deltaHedgeType{
    width:40;
}
#mygrid .quoteccy{
    width:80;
}
```

what come in my mind append this css in header in  tag. coz IE browser have limitation of  count and also its increase the html size of the page. so how do i append this css in  style.css.

Comment: You can change css property's value dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse mygrid._struct to get fieldType  and defaultWidth and then for each eleement use following code

The final javascript to add css will be

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '#mygrid.'+fieldType+'{ width:'+defaultWidth+'; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

For ie limit either use an id on one of the already used style and refere it using jquery or create an new one and append all ur style to this one.

```
           $style = $('#MyGridStyle');
          if (!$style[0]) {
            $style = $("<style id='MyGridStyle' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />").appendTo($("head"));
          }
```

now use this $style to add to this

Refer [IE 8 and 7 bug when dynamically adding a stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618742/ie-8-and-7-bug-when-dynamically-adding-a-stylesheet) for another solution

Comment: i have this solution. what i want is the css append to style.css not in html

Comment: What will be benifit of adding to style.css as it will be only a local change and will be reverted back to old one once page is refreshed.

Comment: where i am using this grid is single page application. and more than 15 grid going to use and each grid have more than 20 column. so the size of css will be huge. and other limitation as i mention in my question that IE have limit on appending <style> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the CSS directly to the head of the html page - I found a good example here: [Add CSS to <head> with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922139/add-css-to-head-with-javascript)

Comment: i have this solution. what i want is the css append to style.css not in html

Comment: I found an article doing just that on David Walsh's blog [http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets)

Answer (score 0):

Inside CSS file, you could use     `@import url("/css/filename.css")`to import a new css file which is dynamically refreshed and use for some special purpose.