# How to dynamically create CSS class in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, ie8-browser-mode

I need to create a CSS stylesheet class dynamically using JavaScript in IE8.

I have used following code for other browsers:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.cssClass { color: #F00; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

it's working fine in all browsers except IE8. How to achieve the same in IE8?

Comment: You could simply insert the style to the body of the page with in <style></style>

Comment: @Taplar i need to apped dynamically

Comment: You can. http://jsfiddle.net/dzv1p8vf/1/

Comment: This problem has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5618889/299756

Comment: @taplar that's not working in ie 8

Comment: @kalyfe 

i have used css like this

var text = ".highlightStyle { fill:" + fill + ";opacity:" + opacity + ";stroke:" + strokeColor + ";stroke-width:" + strokeWidth + "+ }";

fill , opacity, strokeColor and strokeWidth are variable which changed dynamically... those attributes are working fine in all browser except IE8 in IE8 fill , strokeColor,strokeWidth, opacity properties are not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897.aspx):

> The innerHTML property is read-only on the col, colGroup, frameSet, html, head, style, table, tBody, tFoot, tHead, title, and tr objects.

So, try to use `innerText` to write these class.

**Updated**:

You can use:

```
style.styleSheet.cssText = '.cssClass { color: #F00; }';
```

Or do a test:

```
if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = '.cssClass { color: #F00; }';
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode('.cssClass { color: #F00; }'));
}
```

Hope, it now runs! :)

Comment: Ok, wait for a while!

Comment: @ Radonirina Maminiaina i have used css like this var text = ".highlightStyle { fill:" + fill + ";opacity:" + opacity + ";stroke:" + strokeColor + ";stroke-width:" + strokeWidth + "+ }"; fill , opacity, strokeColor and strokeWidth are variable which changed dynamically... those attributes are working fine in all browser except IE8 in IE8 fill , strokeColor,strokeWidth, opacity properties are not working

Comment: IE8 is a very old browser, but you can see this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ for the opacity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77187/discussion-between-radonirina-maminiaina-and-akbar-basha).

Comment: @ Radonirina Maminiaina  sure