# innerHTML is not working in IE8 browser on dynamic update in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created styles tag dynamically using javascript. Then create styles and assign to style object innerHTML dynamically. But it doesn't work in IE8 browser

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erd3hbj8/

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
 style.type = 'text/css';
 style.innerHTML = ".myStyle{background-color: red;}";
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Anyone help on this.

Thanks,
Bharathi

Comment: there is different attribute, not innerHTML

Comment: it relates to this question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099441/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-ie8?noredirect=1#comment48311098_30099441 can you please check this

Comment: This is not the correct way to add stylesheets to a page.